# C++ no operator matches these operands operand types are: std::ostream << std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>

Tags: c++

I don't know why I got this error.

The system will give this error when program compiles to below code.

```
cout << v;
```

If anyone knows how to fix this error, pleae help me.

Thanks you so much.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int>v;
    int n;
    n = v.size();
    int in;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> in;
        v.push_back(in);
        sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    };
    cout << v;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `operator<<` has no overload for printing `vector`s because there is no universal agreement on how a `vector` should be formatted when printed. Typically you'll have to loop through the `vector` and print out the items in it yourself applying whatever formatting you like.

Comment: `auto operator<<(ostream& out, vector<int> const& v) -> ostream& { auto sep = ""; for(auto x : v) out << exchange(sep, " ") << x; return out; }`